# Issue with adding node to linked list from class

Tags: c#, linked-list

I have created phonebook, I wish to add a object of PersonalData into node of list. I get error when I do this though, this is my code.

I have my PersonalData class

```
class PersonalData
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Number { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }        

public PersonalData(string name, string number, string email )
{
    this.Name = name;
    this.Number = number;
    this.Email = email;   
}
```

}

In list cs.

```
public LinkedList Linklist = new LinkedList();
public string m_Name 
public string m_Number 
public string m_Email 

Linklist.addtolist(new PersonalData(m_Name, m_Number, m_Email){});
```

to ad node i has

```
public void addtolist(string name, string number, string email)
{
Node NouNode = new Node() { }
.....
```

I get issue with addtolist because no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter. But I do not know how to have  Node NouNode = new Node() { } to make the addtolist work.

I hope english good to understand, if not i can fix more.

EDIT: OK I CHANGE. I use

```
static public LinkedList<PersonalData> linklist = new LinkedList<PersonalData>();
```

and add by

```
Linklist.addtolist(new PersonalData(m_Name, m_Number, m_Email){});
```

my list class is

```
class LinkedList<PersonalData>
{
    private Node head;
    private Node current;
    public int node;

public LinkedList()
    {
        head = new Node();
        current = head;
    }

public void addtolist(string name, string number, string email)
{
Node NouNode = new Node() { }
......
```

I am still have issue with linklist.addtolist saying no arguments given, is this cause I have nothing in the new node, but i do not know how to set up node, what to put in as arguments?

Comment: I forgot to put the add method. i add to main body

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define LinkedList differently:

```
public LinkedList<PersonalData> Linklist = new LinkedList<PersonalData>();
```

and add the item:

```
Linklist.Add(new PersonalData() {});
```

Comment: If I do that way, is that using the built in list function. I cannot do that i am not aloud to do that. I need to create my own list structure?

Comment: If you need to create your own list, then look into the yield function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt809121.aspx

Comment: Search online for 'C# iterator pattern'

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code
First, you have to define the type which LinkedList is going to store
Second There is no addtolist method
--It does not have Add method too

to fix use below code

```
LinkedList<PersonalData> Linklist = new LinkedList<PersonalData>();
Linklist.AddLast(new PersonalData(m_Name, m_Number, m_Email));
```

For more information on LinkedList view [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) link

---

Update:
Now you are asking a new question:
Do not forget basic programming rules, your method needs 3 strings but you are giving it an object of class, re-read your code and make sure input types are ok

Comment: I do not know how to use code in this box, so i add to main body of question, an update of question